# Can't Start Minecraft with Command Line

Tags: java, python, batch-file, minecraft, launcher

I tried to start minecraft with these args:

```py
arguments = ["javaw.exe", "-Xmx"+str(max_mem), "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode",
                     "-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy", "-Xmn"+str(min_mem),
                     "-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump",
                     "-Djava.library.path="+natives_dir, "-Dminecraft.launcher.brand=java-minecraft-launcher",
                     "-Dminecraft.launcher.version=1.6.89-j",
                     "-cp "+libraries,
                     "net.minecraft.client.main.Main", "--username "+player, "--version "+MINECRAFT_VERSION,
                     "--accessToken 0", "--userProperties {}", "--gameDir "+CLIENT_PATH, "--assetsDir "+assets_dir,
                     "--assetIndex ", "--width "+width, "--height "+height]
```

However, I receive this error:

```
Unrecognized option: -cp C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/ca/weblite/java-objc-bridge/1.0.0/java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/ibm/icu/icu4j-core-mojang/51.2/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/mojang/authlib/1.5.25/authlib-1.5.25.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/mojang/patchy/1.1/patchy-1.1.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/mojang/realms/1.10.22/realms-1.10.22.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/mojang/text2speech/1.10.3/text2speech-1.10.3.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/paulscode/codecwav/20101023/codecwav-20101023.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/com/paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/io/netty/netty-all/4.1.9.Final/netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.1.0/fastutil-7.1.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.4.0/jna-4.4.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput/2.0.5/jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/java/jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/java/jutils/jutils/1.0.0/jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.3/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.8.1/log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl-2.9.2-nightly-20140822.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl-platform-2.9.2-nightly-20140822-natives-windows.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.2-nightly-20140822/lwjgl_util-2.9.2-nightly-20140822.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/libraries/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:/Users/danch/AppData/Roaming/.launcor/versions/1.12.2/1.12.2.jar
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: if there is space between argument and value then you have to create two elements on list `[..., "-cp",  libraries, ...]`. You may have the same problem with other arguments which have space.

Answer (score 1):

It's not

```
"-cp "+libraries,
```

it is

```
"-cp",
libraries,
```

Everywhere you would type a space on the command line is a new argument! So you have to change this in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `-classpath` instead of `-cp`.

Not sure if that's because of your Java version or what.